# While loop won't stop looping Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, iteration

I have created simple table called Reservations and this table have following columns: ID, DUE_DATE, PRODUCTS_PAID, RESERVATION_NAME, SALE, TOTAL_SELL_PRICE and CUSTOMER_ID.

Now what I want to do is that I want to iterate through this table where CUSTOMER_ID is given value. Here is my method that collects all those columns data by CUSTOMER_ID:

```
   public Collection<Reservations> findReservation(int cuID) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Reservations r WHERE r.customerData.id = :cID");
    q.setParameter("cID", cuID);
    List results = q.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

My problem here is that whenever I run iteration loop it won't stop iterating but it continues to iterate. I have only two rows of data in that table. Can you tell me why this iteration continues and won't stop? Obviously I just want to iterate all data inside of that table based on given CUSTOMER_ID value.

I have tried for loops, for each loops and while loops and non of them works. It must be something to do with my code. Here is one while loop that I tested but it won't stop iteration like the rest loops:

```
       for(Iterator itr2 = rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator(); itr2.hasNext();){
        rModel.addRow(Arrays.asList(rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getId(), 
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getReservationName(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getCustomerData().getCustomerName(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getCustomerData().getCustomerType(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getDueDate(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getTotalSellPrice(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getSale(),
                rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next().getProductsPaid(),
                "Print"));
    }
```

If you wonder what is cuID, its just an integer value which is received from table column. This value is customerID. It works well. So it shouldn't effect on the code. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: This `rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator().next()` give you the first result from this collection every times.  Are you sure you don't each result, not just the first again and again?

Comment: I know how to return single or result list. That's not a problem and I'm aware of that .next() returns only the next and single element unless you use it inside of iteration.

Comment: In this case, you are starting again every time so next() will only ever return the first one, no matter how many times you iterate through this loop.  BTW You are also performing the query and starting again for each field, for an operation which is already expensive, in total, mind blowingly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:-

```
for(Reservations res : rd.findReservation(cuID)){
    // Do whatever you want with this object(res)
    rModel.addRow(Arrays.asList(res.getId(), res.getReservationName()...);
}
```

This is clean and simple! No need to use iterator in that weird way you've used, which just keeps getting a new iterator and keeps fetching the first entry from that, hence leading to an `infinite` loop!

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't call the `next` on your `iterator` that you have declared in the loop. Try this instead :

```
for(Iterator itr2 = rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator(); itr2.hasNext();){
    MyObject obj = itr2.next();
    rModel.addRow(Arrays.asList(obj.getId(), 
                                obj.getReservationName(),
                                obj.getCustomerData().getCustomerName(),
                                obj.getCustomerData().getCustomerType(),
                                obj.getDueDate(),
                                obj.getTotalSellPrice(),
                                obj.getSale(),
                                obj.getProductsPaid(),
                                "Print"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you use two separate iterators. What you do is this:

```
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
  iterator2.next();
}
```

obviously you won't exhaust iterator1. Use the same iterator in your loop and in rModel line:

```
   Iterator it = rd.findReservation(cuID).iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
     // or whatever your type is
     Object next = it.next();

    rModel.addRow(Arrays.asList(next.getId(), 
            next.getReservationName(),
            next.getCustomerData().getCustomerName(),
            next.getCustomerData().getCustomerType(),
            next.getDueDate(),
            next.getTotalSellPrice(),
            next.getSale(),
            next.getProductsPaid(),
            "Print"));
}
```